# Marketing Cloud Business Unit - tracking data

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data

I have a need to bring two existing Business units into one. I have all of the standard tracking data stored in them both (Linked by a parent). I would like to be able to maintain all of the data but I can't see a way of being able to get this all into one. Users would want to be able to filter based on last sends etc. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Tracking data is business unit specific. If you want to merge two business units into one, the tracking data will not be consolidated. As a workaround you can create query activities on data views to extract the tracking information and put into a seperate data extension. If a user wants to see the historic tracking data they may need to search this data extension based on subscriber key.

Comment: Did the above solved your query? If yes please accept it as answer for the other's reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to store the data in [Shared Data Extensions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_shared_data_extensions.htm&type=5) since the data is on two separate business units.

Understand that if you have subscribers in one business unit that are not in the other, you will not be able to join the tracking data but you can still have a consolidated view of tracking data.

Use [Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) to pull in the [_Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5), [_Open](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5), [_Click](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5), etc. Note that the data in Data Views only goes back 6 months so you'll have to keep adding to this data extension if you want a longer time frame.